# How to make a symlink from /A to /B, from running in /C

Tags: symlink

If I'm currently in location C, can you make a symlink from /A to /B, from running in /C?

Seems like I need to be in the dir I am creating the ln -s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just use paths to where you want the symlinks to be. Linking to a file called "hi" in b_dir, we would do.

```
[_@blank c_dir]$ ln -s ~/Documents/symlinktest/b_dir/hi    ~/Documents/symlinktest/a_dir/hello
[_@blank c_dir]$ ls ~/Documents/symlinktest/a_dir/
hello
```

Or, with relative paths, we can do:

```
[_@blank c_dir]$ ln -s ../b_dir/hi ../a_dir/hey
```

Comment: I am doing that but I get broken links

Comment: you are right, I thought it was relative to C, but its form /A

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be in the directories to create links. Links can be created from anywhere, as long as you know the target and link name. For more information see  the `man ln` or  `info coreutils 'ln invocation'`, the latter's initial output is as follows (from CentOS 6.6):

```
File: coreutils.info,  Node: ln invocation,  Next: mkdir invocation,  Prev: link invocation,  Up: Special file types

12.2 `ln': Make links between files
===================================

`ln' makes links between files.  By default, it makes hard links; with
the `-s' option, it makes symbolic (or "soft") links.  Synopses:

     ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINKNAME
     ln [OPTION]... TARGET
     ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY
     ln [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY TARGET...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
ln -s  /A /B
```

Note : /A and /B should be full path if you running from /C.